# NetSuite to Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, salesforce, netsuite

I am using NetSuite, which is an Oracle based platform. Is there a way that I can connect NetSuite and Google BigQuery? I want to directly get data into BigQuery from NetSuite. I also have the same question for Salesforce

Comment: Hi Nicole! Did you figured out how to connect NetSuite with BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, not sure if it is going to help still.

We use Fivetran for Schema and table content sync from NetSuite to BigQuery